# Symbols not found during linking

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have a problem with a shared library (Linux) and a program that links against this library but does not find the symbols - although they are there. That's what I have:

A shared library "libetest.so" that is located in /usr/lib. When I do an

```
 readelf -Ws /usr/lib/libetest.so.0
```

it gives (beside some others) this output:

```
54: 000052c0   905 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 ETEST_open_connection
```

Now I have an application that makes use of ETEST_open_connection(). When I build it with

```
gcc lib_test.cpp -DENV_LINUX -letest
```

it fails with a linker error

```
lib_test.cpp:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `ETEST_open_connection'
```

As shown before the symbol is there! Any idea why this fails?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try:

```
gcc -DENV_LINUX -letest lib_test.cpp
```

This should be the correct argument order.

Comment: Sorry, no, that does not make a difference. Also using ++ (since it is a .cpp file) does not solve this...

Comment: Oh okay ;) Well you must use g++. Tge problem here is that c++ uses a different name for this function. You have to declare it with extern "C" so that the linker uses the C name for this function

Comment: And lib_test.cpp includes exactly this header file?

Comment: Yes...more funny: it was copied from a different project which is working (names/symbols of course have been changed).

Comment: Yes...your ideas helped me to found the reason, there was an other #ifdef condition prevented the application to use the correct export definitions - thanks!